# LSI 9211-8 or 9650se for a ZFS Pool

Tags: raid, zfs, hba, smartos

I'm putting together a white box (smartos) for our dev team with some of the leftover hardware we have. The server chassis I'm going to use has 8 swappable drives and I'm trying to determine which hba card to use for the ZFS Pool.

I have both the LSI 9211 and the older 9650se. I can run the 9211 in IT mode or the 9650se in JBOD.  I was wondering if anyone had experience with either card with ZFS and can save me some time on performance testing.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/search?tab=votes&q=9211-8i

Comment: @ewwhite is your recommendation to go with 9211? I know a lot of people use it but I was more curious on pros/cons in comparison to the 9650se. https://serverfault.com/search?q=9211-8i+9650se